# Set default value to Form:text() in Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-4

Well, I am so lost in how to achieve this behavior. In my view I have this:

```
Form::text('time', Input::old('time'));
```

So, everything the form validator fails, the view is rendered again with the *time* input having the value that the user typed in the past... Everything is ok here.

What I want to do is to display a default in the time input from the beginning, something like this:

```
time:  [ now      ]
```

But if the user change the "now" word and the validator fails, I would like to the display the text submitted by the user instead of "now".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Laravel 4, you don't have to explicitly tell it to load the old data, it will do this for you since you're using the `Form::text` macro.

So something like this will work for you:

```
Form::text('time', 'now');
```

That will set 'now' as the default, but if there is a value in `Input::old('time')` it will magically appear as the default.

You will need to ensure that you are redirecting back the form `with input` like this:

```
return Redirect::route('your.route')->withInput();
```

If you want to see the magic behind this, see the code [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Html/FormBuilder.php#L258), then [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Html/FormBuilder.php#L235), then finally [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Html/FormBuilder.php#L878)

Comment: Thank you so much. I have combined your answer with this line in the controller: `return Redirect::to("edit/article/3")->withInput()->withErrors($validator);`

Comment: perfect, sorry, I should have mentioned making the return with input, will mod the answer to show this